# Copying a xsd:complex-type element to another xsd:complex-type element using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have following input .xsd structure:

```
<xs:element name="branches" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="branch" type="branch" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="branch">
    <xs:element name="container" type="cNameAndVersion" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="branchMapping" minOccurs="0">
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="cNameAndVersion">
<xs:sequence/>
<xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:long" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

In my new file, branch should contain list of container-level mappings (instead of only one container), but with copied name and version of previous container. It looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="branch">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:complexType name="containerLeveMappings">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="containerLevelMapping" type="containerLevelMappingEntry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="branchMapping" minOccurs="0">
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name=" containerLevelMappingEntry ">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="container" type=" cNameAndVersion " minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="levels" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="level" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

From what I understand, I have 3 things to do here:

1. Add new element "containerLevelMappings" to branch
2. Copy value from old branch/**container** to new entry of branch/containerLevelMapping/Entry(**container**, level)
3. Remove branch/container from file

I have problem with 2). I don't know how to iterate over all branches and copy their containers to new containerLevelMappings.
What I've done for now in XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/branches/branch/branchMapping">
            <xsl:element name="containerLeveMappings">
                <xsl:element name="containerLeveMapping">
                    <xsl:element name="container">
                        <xsl:attribute name="version">
                            <xsl:value-of select = "../container/version" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="../container/name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="levels"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root/branches/branch/container"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately both 'version' and 'name' are empty strings while unmarshmaling the new xml file.

In other words, I would like to transform this part of xml:

```
<branches>
<branch>
    <container name="name_1" version="2"/>
    <branchMapping/>
</branch>
<branch>
    <container name="name_2" version="3"/>
    <branchMapping/>
</branch>
</branches>
```

To this form:

```
<branches>
<branch>
<containerLevelMappings>
    <containerLevelMapping>
        <container name="name_1" version="2"/>
        <level/>
    </containerLevelMapping>
</containerLevelMappings>
<branchMapping/>
</branch>
<branch>
    <containerLevelMappings>
        <containerLevelMapping>
            <container name="name_2" version="3"/>
            <levels/>
        </containerLevelMapping>
    </containerLevelMappings>
    <branchMapping/>
</branch>
</branches>
```

Maybe somebody can tell me where is my mistake here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` and `version` are attributes, so they need to be `@name` and `@version`.

Your code can be simplified to:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/branches/branch/branchMapping">
    <containerLevelMappings>
        <containerLevelMapping>
            <container version="{../container/@version}" 
                       name="{../container/@name}"/>
            <levels/>
        </containerLevelMapping >
    </containerLevelMappings>
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I also corrected a couple of spelling mistakes in element names - they stand out more clearly if you use the more concise syntax.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much!